# JSONException: No Value for

Tags: android, json

I have some problem, in logcat says

```
D/JSON Parser: ����������µM@@ÿJÌYÁ5õfyo]"dÄM]wÅ]ÿ{kXôuí4ðÌ<fR)Îd
               ña,-8vbðp@botSâ¯&©V ±4Ý~HÌBSBÓN<¸¸?sN{UÑãHIrR`ÊN´AÓë¢£Ò °|£äu
               `t¾r¿j3Ê+~¤çÿ-]ÏoÖõ\S1q ¥úõÔ7©ÀAT����
E/JSON Parser:Errorparsing data org.json.JSONException:
              Value����������µM@@ÿJÌYÁ5õfyo of type java.lang.String
              cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

This is my code:

```
 public static final String TAG_BOOK = "booking"; 
        Log.d("book: ", jObject.toString());
        try{
            int sukses = jObject.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (sukses == 1){
                booking = jObject.getJSONArray(TAG_BOOK);
                booklist.removeAll(booklist);
                for (int i = 0;i < booking.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = booking.getJSONObject(i);
                    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    String id = obj.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String nKend = obj.getString(TAG_KENDARAAN);
                    String sttus = obj.getString(TAG_STATUSBOOK);

                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_KENDARAAN, nKend);
                    map.put(TAG_STATUSBOOK, sttus);
                    map.put(TAG_INDEX, ""+i);

                    booklist.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is my JSON Object

```
{
"booking": [
    {
      "ID_kendaraan": "26",
      "nama_kendaraan": "Vario 125",
      "no_plat": "DK6281AI",
      "tgl_sewa": "2016-11-02",
      "tgl_kembali": "2016-11-09",
      "nama_belakang": "Maong",
      "status_rental": "Confirmed"
    },
    {
      "ID_kendaraan": "3",
      "nama_kendaraan": "Avanza",
      "no_plat": "DK890OO",
      "tgl_sewa": "2016-11-02",
      "tgl_kembali": "2016-11-09",
      "nama_belakang": "Maong",
      "status_rental": "Booking"
    }
],
    "sukses": 1, 
    "pesan": "Booking"
}
```

when im using postman to try get JSONobject its work like on my JSON object before but in Logcat cant get my json object. im new in here so please help, sorry for bad english. Thanks

Comment: No value for booking

Comment: This is not the way of converting JSON object to string .

Comment: Either you print the whole response or print each parameter after parsing .

Answer (score 0):

You should check first if

```
JSONObject obj = booking.getJSONObject(i);
if(obj.has("object_withno_value")) { 
    //Code if it has
}
```